# How to create an mu4e action to forward and send a message?

Tags: mu4e

My email service uses spamhero as a spam filter system. When I get a spam message into my INBOX, I forward that message to a given email address. I would like to be able to create an action to do all of this work for me. I can create an action easily enough to call mu4e-compose-forward but that leaves me still to do all the hard work (selecting context, entering email address and sending the message).

I have a feeling I can not use mu4e-compose-forward as it requires too much user interaction. Instead call a lower level function with the message content, but I'm failing to find the right direction.

Any pointers to where to go next?

Comment: My guess would be `(mu4e-compose 'forward)` then: insert the address, send and exit, but for some reason it doesn't work. It may be a bug.

Comment: I'll do some digging there, thanks for the pointer.